# QUé obtengo con $('#img') en jQuery?

Tags: jquery

quisiera saber que que me devuelve en jQuery(suponiendo que tengo una etiqueta HTML img con id = 'img'):

```
$('#img');
```

Cuando lo utilizo me devuelve "null", pero cuando le coloco un metodo, por ejemplo:

```
$('#img').width;
```

Me devuelve algo que empieza asi(Es muy largo, no pondré todo):

> ƒ (e,t){var n=arguments.length&&(r||"boolean"!=typeof
> e),i=r||(!0===e||!0===t?"margin":"border");return
> $(this,function(e,t,n){var r;return
> x(e)?0===o.indexOf("outer")?e["inner"+a]:e.document.documentE…

Quisiera saber que significa eso, por favor. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acceder al elemento de esta manera:

```
$(function () {
    var img = document.getElementById('img');
    console.log(img);
});
```

Al imprimir la variable "img" en la consola mostrará las propiedades de la misma ->

```
HTMLImageElement {tagName: "img", attributes: {…}, innerHTML: "", nodeType: 1…}
attributes: Object
id: "img"
src: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoII...="
width: "250px"
__proto__: Object
innerHTML: ""
nodeType: 1
tagName: "img"
__proto__: HTMLImageElement
```

Si en HTML el tag **img** no tiene el **id** la impresión en consola retornará **null**

En este punto ya puedes jugar con el objeto

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres saber los atributos de esa etiqueta como objeto, podrias hacer lo siguiente:

1. Crea una variable y asignale la etiqueta:

var imagen=$('#img') ;

2. Luego en consola imprime la variable:

console.log(imagen) ;

Allí veras todos los atributos que puede tener la etiqueta como objeto.